# Automating & Simplifying Crossbrowser Support

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser

A lot of the stuff that I seem to end up doing to support older less-than-compliant browsers seems to be (1) repetitive and (2) easy to forget. Two things that indicate to me they should probably be dealt with by a computer instead of my brain.

For instance, anywhere I use...

```
.element-selector {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

...in order to support IE7 I actually need to apply the additional rules...

```
.element-selector {
    display: inline-block;
    /* IE7 */
    zoom: 1;
    display: inline;
    /* End IE7 */
}
```

...in order for things to render properly in IE7.

I'm not sure exactly what I'm asking for here. But it seems like there should be something that I can setup to "do this for me". Maybe some script that statically analyzes my CSS docs and inserts these things? Some crazy jQuery plugin that inserts them into the DOM? Some CSS generating pseudo-language that allows for the automated creation of CSS documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Automating & Simplifying Crossbrowser
>   Support

I'm assuming by "Crossbrowser", you're mostly talking about Internet Explorer. It is the biggest troublemaker, and some of the older versions [are still](http://ie6countdown.com/) in annoyingly widespread usage. The usage of older versions of *other browsers* is negligible enough that you can forget about them.

It looks like you've (wisely) already forgotten about older versions of non-IE browsers; to make (your example) `display: inline-block` work in Firefox 2, [you need `display: -moz-inline-stack`](http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/).

> Some crazy jQuery plugin that inserts
>   them into the DOM?

Not jQuery :) But this fixes many issues: http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

> IE9.js - Upgrade MSIE5.5-8 to be
>   compatible with modern browsers.

I do have to point out that anything JavaScript based obviously won't work when JavaScript is turned off.

> Maybe some script that statically
>   analyzes my CSS docs and inserts these
>   things?

The closest thing I can think of to that is this: http://www.onderhond.com/tools/ie6fixer/

> Welcome to the IE6 CSS Fixer: starter
>   kit page. A tool specifically designed
>   to ease the pain of the ie6 css
>   debugger. .. It is extremely
>   important to note that this tool is
>   not a miracle solution. .. In some
>   circumstances it can even introduce
>   new errors, so keep that in mind when
>   you add one of the potentially
>   harmfull fixes. Also know that it does
>   not output clean, lean and optimized
>   css code. .. This tool was concieved
>   to decrease the monkey work when
>   starting an ie6 css fix file. It
>   applies a series of basic fixes that
>   are known to conquer many problems and
>   cause as little harm as possible.

It only specifically tries to fix IE6 related issues, which is thankfully becoming less and less important.

Comment: Yes, you are correct in that we were mostly thinking about only supporting IE back to 7 and alternative browsers only back to FF3-ish.

Comment: A lot of the more *common* IE7 issues are already handled by http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/ - those that aren't are by definition difficult to fix automatically with code, or that script would be fixing them. A lot of IE7 issues are fixed by applying [`hasLayout`](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html), typically with `zoom: 1` - but you can't add that to everything, because in other circumstances it *causes* problems. I guess what I'm saying is that what you're asking for doesn't exist (except for the ideas in my answer), and wouldn't be worth making - IE7 has really low usage.

Answer (score 1):

Something like Sass or Less can help you with that. You can define mixins and use those.

```
.inline-mix {
    display: inline-block;
    /* IE7 */
    zoom: 1;
    display: inline;
    /* End IE7 */
}
.element-selector {
    .inline-mix;
}
```

This isn't an automated solution but it can help a little to dry up your css.

Comment: You should point out that he either has to use `*display: inline` to feed it to only IE7 (invalid CSS, but my preferred method regardless). If not that, can SASS/LESS otherwise help to handle the IE7-only rule? *(I don't know SASS or LESS)*

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a compliance project team for a large bank, redoing over 1,000 websites for their credit card business.  Requirements were ridiculously strict and specified backwards compatibility for users below IE6, screenreader support, and lack of javascript/images.  The single tool that made it quick and possible was [960.gs](http://www.960.gs)

The reset took us back to baseline, and eliminated the need for quite a few IE specific hacks (they were already done by the code)  The grids eliminated box-model deficiencies of IE, and helped ensure that layout wasn't eating up time in the production process.  The time saved allowed us to exceed production expectations and more thoroughly test, which was a win all around.

In my time there, I wasn't allowed to use JQuery, used EXTREMELY sparce Javascript, and 3 total IE hacks across hundreds of pages.  The only way that was possible was with grids.  It's not a super high-tech, sexy answer.  But, I swear by the idea of a battle tested framework to speed up production.